# How to iterate through loop of a string to compare with another string's index?

Tags: c, string, loops, conditional-statements, cs50

I am currently facing a problem while coding. The problem is I want to loop through a string and compare each index with another string's index. And at the same time, copy the character to the other string if it does not have it yet. The code below is where I got stuck:

I compiled this and got the error: `comparison between pointer and integer ('char' and 'string' (aka 'char *')) [-Werror,-Wpointer-integer-compare]`

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[1])
{
    string key = argv[1], key2[26];

 for (int i = 0; key[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;

        if (key[i] != key2[j]) // I got an error here
        {
            key2[j] = key[i];
            j++
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", key2);
}
```

Comment: Good that OP has enabled many warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This shows why you shouldn't hide a pointer behind a `typedef` and why hiding how C works from novice programmers doesn't benefit anyone.

There is no `string` type in C. `string` here is just a `typedef` for a `char *`. The following statement:

```
string key = argv[1], key2[26];
```

allocates memory for a `char *`, and an `array[26]` of `char *`, which are not synonymous.

Or in other words:
It declares:

```
char *key = argv[1];
char *key2[26];
```

Note that the these statements only allocated memory for the pointers, not what they point to. In this case, you did initialize `key`, but forgot to initialize `key2`.

The statement:

```
if (key[i] != key2[j])
```

is then invalid. Because `key[i]` evaluates to a `char`, where `key2[j]` evaluates to a `char *` (that you didn't allocate memory for, nor initialize).

---

***Fix:***

Simply declare `key2` to be a `char *`, not an array of `char *`s.

Now find the length of `argv[1]` before copying (it could result in an overflow elsewise).

```
size_t len = strlen (argv[1]);
```

Now allocate memory for `key2`:

```
char *key2 = malloc (len + 1); /* One for the '\0' byte */
if (!key2) {
    /* ENOMEM, handle error accordingly */
}
```

Now copy the strings with `strcpy()` and continue on with the loop. And `free()` the memory when you're done with it.

---

**Minor:** You are accessing `argv[1]` before checking if its valid.

```
 if (argc != 2) {
     fprintf (stderr, "/* Print usage message here */.\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**An array of 26 `char` is needed, not 26 `string`**

```
// string key = argv[1], key2[26];
string key = argv[1];
char key2[26];
```

**`key2[]` not initialized**

Unclear how OP wants to populate this.  Perhaps from next argument?

**Best to test `argc` first**

```
if (argc < 2) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Missing argument\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
string key = argv[1];
...
```

**Drop unneeded `1`**

```
// int main(int argc, string argv[1])
int main(int argc, string argv[])
```